# Analysis interesting exercise. How can I use continuity here?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Consider the following problem.

Let $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f> 0$ and suppose $\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt=3$.

Show that there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for every $x\in [0,\delta]$ there is a unique $y\in [0,1]$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int_{x}^{y}f(t)dt=2.
\end{equation}

My attempt:

If we find such $\delta>0$, and if $x_{0}\in[0,\delta]$, then the function

\begin{equation}F(y)=\int_{x_{0}}^{y}f(t)dt
\end{equation}
seems to be stricly increasing (because $f> 0$) and hence the unicity will follow from this fact together with the continuity of $F$.

About existence of $\delta>0$, I have no idea. Thought for a while on how to use continuity of the function itself of the definition of the integral but I'm having a hard time. Help will be appreciated.

Also, is the unicity argument ok? Thank you.

Comment: Uniqueness of $y$ for each $x$ is clearly not true. It is entirely possible that $f(x)>0$ for $x\in(1,\frac12)$, then $f=0$ on $[\frac12,\frac34]$ and finally $f>0$ on $(\frac34,1)$, and everything such that $\int_0^{1/2} f\,dx=2$ and $\int_{3/4}^1 f\,dx=1$. Then, every $y\in \frac 34$ will work for $x=0$.

Comment: I think this could be a mistake by my part of interpreting a "positive function" as it is written in the text I found as $f\geq 0$ instead of $f>0$.  Oh I see, we need strictly increasing, obviously

Comment: It's the first sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Pick $\delta$ so that $\int_{\delta}^1 f(t) dt = 2$. (You still need to argue why such a $\delta$ exists, but it does.)

Further hint: Then for $x_0 \leq \delta$, $\int_{x_0}^1 f(t) dt \geq \int_{\delta}^1 f(t) dt = 2$ and $\int_{x_0}^{x_0} f(t) dt = 0$, so you can use the intermediate value theorem to produce a $y$, and the strict monotonicity you observed to prove it is unique.

(Oops: a G. Sassatelli points out -- you don't have strict monotonocity. You need to assume that $f > 0$.)

I don't think continuity of $f$ is strictly necessary, but maybe it is included in the problem so you are guaranteed that $\int_a^b f dt$ ,makes sense, and so that you can use the fundamental theorem of calculus.  (Though maybe I'm missing something.)

Comment: Thank you man. I think I can finish now

Comment: @Shoutre You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

The unicity argument is correct.

A hint for the existence: show that there is some $\delta>0$ for which $$\int_\delta^1f(t)dt>2$$
and then show that this $\delta$ meets the requirements.